# Loop not re-looping

Tags: bash, shell-script

currently doing a loop using bash script and based on Shortest Job First (SJF). The loop does not re-loop to check if previously skipped service time are re-checked. Do I need another loop & boolean for checking? Thanks!

Arrival Time:Service Time 
0:3 
1:5 
4:5 
5:1 
6:3 
9:1

```
#execution of second process till last process of SPN   
for (( i=1; i<array; i++ )); do
    prevTime=${finishTime[$value]} #obtain value from previous completion time
    curService=${serviceTime[$i]}
    for (( j=i; j<array; j++ )); do
        #compare previous completion time with current process.
        if [[ $prevTime -ge ${arrivalTime[$j]} ]] && [[ $curService -ge ${serviceTime[$j]} ]]; then
            curService=${serviceTime[$j]}
            value=$j
        fi
    done

    #calculation of each process finish & turnaround time
    finishTime[$value]=`expr $prevTime + ${serviceTime[$value]}`
    turnaroundTime[$value]=`expr ${finishTime[$value]} - ${arrivalTime[$value]}`            
done
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what value is assigned to the variable `array` before your outer loop starts.

Comment: What specifically are you intending to test with `i<array`? I can guess but I need to you tell us.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am guessing that you are trying to estimate job completion ETA based on "randomized" job arrivals for which you provide the arrival time and the job work time pairs, with all jobs being done in serial fashion, not parallel. If that is correct, the logic in the script above for doing the calculations does not seem to make any sense as compared to what I might have come up with. Some parameters don't seem relevant and some calculations don't seem to make sense.  And maybe that is because the above code snippet is not self-contained and insufficient to reproduce your problem.